# How to RETURN @Identity of instert data in spl in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I'm inserting data in a table with this code below.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users (Username,Password,FirstName,lastName,PhoneNumber,Address,City,State,Country,ZipCode,UserType,PayOut,TimeDate)"
                + ("VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + TextBox11.Text + "','User','0','" + Date + "')"), con);                
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I want to get Id of inserting Value in database which I save new data in table anyone have any idea what can i have to add in a code so i can RETURN @Identity of insert value in table and use that id some other code.

Thank you

Comment: To clarify other peoples' answers, `@@Identity` should not be used as it can return the most recent identity across the system (global scope to db), whereas `Scope_Identity()` will return the most recent identity from the current process (local scope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use parametrized queries (to avoid SQL Injection attack)

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO Users (Username,Password,FirstName,lastName,PhoneNumber,Address,City,State,Country,ZipCode,UserType,PayOut,TimeDate)" +
          "values (@username, @password, @firstname, @lastname, @phone, @address, @city, @state, @country, @zipcode, @usertype, @payout, @timedate);" +
          "select SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", TextBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", TextBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone" TextBox6.Text);
//and so on

var id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns last id created for inserted row in given scope. This way you get back id. Use `ExecuteScalar()` method that returns one value from first row, first column.

Also do not store clear text as password, use some hashing method.

Answer (score 1):

change your sql and code like as below

for sql 2005+

```
INSERT INTO Users (UserId,otherdata...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES(@UserId, @othervalues...)
```

for sql 2000

```
INSERT INTO aspnet_GameProfiles(UserId,otherdata...) 
VALUES(@UserId, @othervalues...);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

And then

```
 Int32 newId = (Int32) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Suggestion:

Make use of parameterize query to avoid sql injection attack....

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way would be to append "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()" to your SQL statement.  You should parametrize your query to avoid SQL Injection, and it would look something like:

```
string sql = @"
INSERT INTO Users 
(Username,Password,FirstName,lastName,PhoneNumber,
Address,City,State,Country,ZipCode,UserType,PayOut,TimeDate)
VALUES(@Username, @Password, ...)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, ...);
... append parameters ...
var identity = (decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

If your identity column is an integer, you can either cast from decimal to integer, or do the cast in SQL Server, e.g.

```
string sql = @"
INSERT INTO Users 
...
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)
";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, ...);
... append parameters ...
var identity = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Note that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is generally a better choice than `@@IDENTITY`.  In most cases, they will return the same value.  But, for example, if your INSERT statement causes a trigger to fire, which inserts an identity value in a second table, then it's the identity value inserted into this second table that will be returned by `@@IDENTITY`.  Using SCOPE_IDENTITY avoids this problem.